# Random assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно генерировать случайные числа на ассемблере, с учётом того что код пишется в VS на С++ с ассемблеровской вставкой, т.е. _asm{//asm code }

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем? Учебное задание такое?

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой вариант - реализовать [линейный конгруэнтный генератор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4): `R1 = (a * R0 + b) mod M`. Здесь `a` и `b` - постоянный коэффициенты (подбираются), `M` - модуль, максимальное значение для псевдослучайного числа (минимальным будет 0), `R0` - результат предыдущего вызова генератора (для первого вызова можно подставить любое число).

Answer (score 1):

А можно сделать так, что машинный код будет размещаться в массиве. Вот как можно написать программу для подсчёта количества символов в строке.

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < ctype.h>
char r[]="!!!!!!!!!!!№№№№№№№№№№№;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;55555555555555666666666666666666666666666777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777"; //Строка, длину которой надо определить
main()
{
    static unsigned long  (__cdecl *lenstr)(char*);//Объявление указателя на функцию. Метод передачи параметров надо определить явно - в разных компиляторах разный
    static int i=0;
        if(!i)
            {
                static char s[]={
                    0x5a,
                    //pop %%edx
                    0x5f,
                    //pop %%edi
                    0xfc,
                    //cld
                    0x31,0xc9,
                    //xor %%ecx,%%ecx
                    0x31,0xc0,
                    //xor %%eax,%%eax
                    0x49,
                    //dec %%ecx
                    0xf2,0xae,
                    //repne scasв
                    0xf7,0xd1,
                    //not %%ecx
                    0x49,
                    //dec %%ecx
                    0x91,
                    //xchg %%eax,%%ecx
                    0x52,
                    //push %%edx
                    0xc3
                    //ret
                    };//Массив, в котором машинный код функции
                lenstr=(unsigned long ( __cdecl *)(char*))&s;//Привязка указателя на функцию к данному массиву
                i=1;
            }

            printf("%s%c%d%c%s\n","Длина строки",' ',lenstr(r),' ',"символов");
}
```

Такая программа будет компилироваться на любом компиляторе, вне зависимости от того поддерживает ли компилятор встроенный ассемблер или нет. Трудность только в том, что надо самому переводить в машинный код.